# Implement onclick retrieve

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I need help.

I have a MySQL Database table named CARS. It has columns BRAND, MODEL, TYPE. I want to show 2 select combo box. First combo box should retrieve the BRANDS from Database. And when user selects a BRAND then MODELS of that BRAND should be retrieved in the second select combobox.

Please help.

```
<select id="brands">
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

        <option  value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[0];?></option>

    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but I'll try to understand it.
So, first Combo box should get all brands from DB and second one needs to show its models. 
What you need to do:
You need to call javascript on-click function that will trigger query from database.
Also, you have to send value of selected brand as parameter of function just because you want to make a query with that parameter.

I'm providing you with a helpful link:
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/356822/onclick-get-results-from-php